# Creating a responsive horizontal content thumbnail with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, responsive

I'm having a problem creating a responsive "card" similar to the [Custom Content Thumbnail](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content) in Bootstrap but horizontal. The main problem is that I want the image to be a square and 100% of the height of the card. Also, I want all the cards to have the same width and height.

This is my work so far:

```css
body {
 background-color:#ededed;
 font-family:"Segoe UI";
}

/*----------2.Headings & Buttons----------*/
h3 {
 font-size:1.2em;
 font-weight:600;
 text-transform:capitalize;
 margin:0 0 10px 0;
 padding:0;
 color:#555555;
}
.btn-styled {
 background-color:transparent;
 border:#666666 1.9px solid;
 color:#666666;
 font-size:0.85em;
 border-radius:30px;
 padding:5px 13px 4px 13px;
 margin:10px 0 10px 0;
}
.btn-styled:hover, .btn-styled:active  {
 background-color:#ededed;
 border-color:#ededed;
 color:#555555;
}
.btn-styled:focus {
 outline:0 !important;
}
/*----------3.Cards----------*/
.card {
 position: relative;
   margin:2% 5px 2% 5px;
   background-color: #fff;
   transition: box-shadow .25s;
   border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
 padding:0;
 min-width:400px;
 max-width:500px;
}
.card .card-image img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .card-content {
  padding: 15px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}

.card .card-content p {
  margin:0;
  font-size:1.45rem;
  color: #555555;
}
/*----3.a.Horizontal----*/
.card.horizontal .card-image img {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
}

.card.horizontal {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
}
.card.horizontal.small .card-image,
 .card.horizontal.medium .card-image,
  .card.horizontal.large .card-image {
   height: 100%;
   max-height: none;
   overflow: visible;
}
.card.horizontal .card-image img {
   width:150px;
 height:150px;
 margin-right:20px;
}
.card.horizontal .card-stacked {
   -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
   -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
   position: relative;
}
.card.horizontal .card-stacked .card-content {
   -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
 flex-grow: 1;
}
.card .card-image {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
        <h3>MAIN TITLE</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card horizontal">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/ff/Morning_Glory_Flower_square.jpg/1024px-Morning_Glory_Flower_square.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="card-stacked">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3>Title Goes Here</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,  sed doeiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-styled">START COPY</button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card horizontal">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/ff/Morning_Glory_Flower_square.jpg/1024px-Morning_Glory_Flower_square.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="card-stacked">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3>Title Goes Here</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,  sed doeiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-styled">START COPY</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also, I made an example of how the cards should look in a grid:

[image]

When I tried to create this cards they were not responsive. On different screen widths the left-right-margin was too big or they were on top of each other.

Can someone help get started or give me some ideas how I should do it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some code which represents what you have achieved so far, it would be far easier to help you. A jsfiddle would be a great addition.

Comment: @Yoda Done. Hope you can help now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use bootstrap. Ihave provided a demo link just experiment with the code and read the documentation of bootstrap to get better understanding

Here is your [Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/atalkishore/xy8nunL9/)

**Html Code**

```
    <div class="container">

      <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="card">
          <div class="image pull-left">

          </div>
          <div class="content pull-left">
            <h4>
       Title Goes Here
       </h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            <br>

            <button class="btn btn-default btn-read">
              Read more
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Css code**

```
    .card {
      background: #fff;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .image {
      float: left;
      background: #000;
      width: 25%;
      height: 150px
    }

    .content {
      float: left;
      height: 140px;
      width: 73%;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .content h4 {
      margin: 5px 0;
    }
```